# Maven assembly plugin: building a distributable Java SE application

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm developing a simple, stand-alone, command line Java application. The project is managed by Maven. I'd like to build a deliverable, which can be copied and run on the client's machine.

I'm using the maven assembly plugin, the desired output is a single zip file containing:

- my_product.jar : only my classes, without dependencies
- lib/ : a lib folder containing all the dependencies in .jar format (e.g. lib/log4j.jar, lib/commons-lang.jar)
- a starter script file (copied from somewhere in the project)

How to describe this in an assembly-descriptor file? I'm having trouble creating my_product.jar into the assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predefined 'jar-with-dependencies' assembly is a joke. The problem had been solved by external assistance and heavy customization of the pom.xml and assembly descriptor.

It seems if you diverge from the standard Java EE/webapp path towards the standalone applications then you have to prepare for extensive maven customizations.

Comment: Sorry, don't have access to it any more

Comment: No worries: I found this to be very helpful: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/creating-a-runnable-binary-distribution-with-maven-assembly-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the predefined assemby `jar-with-dependencies`? It should suit your needs.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) for a detailed discussion of creating executable JAR distributions with maven.